# How to 'unplumb' a network interface

Tags: networking, ethernet

I want to remove a un-use network interface on Ubuntu 11.10 desktop but failed.

```
virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:13:97:0c:0f:4f
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4800 (4.8 KB)

me@linux:~$ sudo ifconfig virbr0 down
me@linux:~$ sudo ifconfig virbr0 unplumb
unplumb: Unknown host
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.
```

`unplumb` seem usable in Solaris but not in Ubuntu. Any idea?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the commands below

```
ifconfig virbr0 down
brctl delbr virbr0
```

(most of the time virbr0 is a bridge created by Virtualbox or Xen like hypervisors)

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is explained in full in [this LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/), but here is a snippet:

> In the sysfs tree, every driver now has bind and unbind files associated with it:
>
> ```
> $ tree /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ub/
> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ub/
> |-- 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
> |-- bind
> |-- module -> ../../../../module/ub
> `-- unbind
> ```
>
> In order to unbind a device from a driver, simply write the bus id of the device to the unbind file:
>
> ```
> echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ub/unbind
> ```